# Juno - Java Build Path - project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, jar

I am getting this error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Archive for required library:
>   'src/Program.java' in project 'Home' cannot be read or is not a valid
>   ZIP file  Home Build path Build Path Problem

[image]

[image]

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please follow the navigation as below:

```
Right Click(project) -> Java Build Path ->Libraries
```

Fix all the entries there with `red cross` mark in the front. You also may want to remove them and add them fresh using `remove` and `add` button in the right of the wizard.

Comment: Can you look to my edit post because I don`t know what I have to edit here

Comment: @Rafael..  in libraries tab, you'll see your src files (.java). Remove them

Answer (score 2):

Can you check, if `src/Program.java` is not among your libraries entries (`Java Build Path ->Libraries`)?
There, you should include only `jar` files and directories, not source (`.java`) files.

Comment: I added new picture to my post.

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem. For solve it I removed the problematic lib and I added it again

Answer (score 1):

```
Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> remove struts.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another of those mentioned fixes:

My build system (Gradle) added a required native library (dll) to the Eclipse build path (Right Click on Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries).
Telling the build system not to add the native dll library to the Eclipse classpath solved the problem.