# Error display on project while adding selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0 jar file in eclipse project

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using below configuration :

> Selenium version : selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0
>
> Gecko Driver Version : geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64
>
> Firefox Version : 54.0.1 (32-bit)

Project shows error while adding `selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar` file in java build path.

It work nicely and error removed when adding `selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar` file in java build path.

Find the below screenshots for more information.

[image]

I'm getting following error messages in eclipse console :

> 'C:/selenium-java-3.5.0/lib/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar' in project 'test17' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

And

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

I don't know why this happening? please help.

Comment: Can you consider bumping up `Selenium` to `v3.5.0`, `geckodriver` to `v0.18.0` and `Mozilla Firefox` to stable GA `v53.0`. For additional information watch this [**`Discussion`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510338/selenium-webdriver-3-4-0-geckodriver-0-18-0-firefox-which-combination-w/45510453#45510453)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526072/archive-for-required-library-could-not-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183355/juno-java-build-path-project-cannot-be-read-or-is-not-a-valid-zip-file

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure why you're getting  this error, I would strongly suggest to use project managing tool, Maven for example if your language is Java.

This will solve all Webdriver's and other packages' versions conflicts. If you go with Maven, I would also suggest to use WebdriverManager package from [bonigarcia](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

Comment: This error solved after configuring my project with maven. Thanks @Mykola